# How to highlight the first occurence of a month in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using conditional formatting in Google Sheets, I'd like to be able to highlight ONLY the first date/entry of a month within a long list of dates, even with repeated dates.

See below list for an example of what I'd like to be highlighted:

| A |
| --- |
| **Jan 1, 2024** |
| Jan 1, 2024 |
| Jan 4, 2024 |
| **March 4, 2024** |
| March 4, 2024 |
| March 10, 2024 |
| March 24, 2024 |
| **August 10, 2024** |
| August 12, 2024 |
| **November 3, 2024** |
| November 28, 2024 |

etc

What conditional formatting rules can I use to achieve the highlighting in the above example?

###### What I've tried

Tried using the `=DAY($A1)=1` formula but it only highlights the dates that are on the 1st.

Also tried using `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1` but it highlights every unique occurrence which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The following works

```js
=A1=index(filter(A:A,month(A:A)=month(A1)))
```

The reasoning is apparent in the functions. `filter` gets you dates whose month equals the month of the current cell and outputs the result in an inline column. The `index` call, equivalent as `index(...,1,1)`, extracts the 1st cell of that inline column, meaning the 1st date, which is what you asked for.

---

Additionally, in case you want to highlight the earliest date of a month in the column, you can do

```js
=A1=sortn(filter(A:A,month(A:A)=month(A1)))
```

(For your particular example of sorted list of dates, the two requirements are equivalent.)

---

Column B below shows how 1st occurrences are highlighted; column C shows earliest dates, using the respective formulas, and for a less normalized example.

[image]

---

### Bonus: O(n) solution

If there are (very) many entries in your sheet, you may need a solution that does not traverse the date column unnecessarily. Indeed, once a date has chosen to be highlighted, no more dates from the same month needs to be checked again if we are allowed to keep track of that status as we traverse the date column. If we have such a status list, we only need to traverse the date column once, and would therefore have an O(n) solution. We do need to traverse the date column at least once, so we also know this is as efficient as it can get.

> What is very many entries? In my experience, in Google Sheet, O(n^2) formulas often start to have issues with several thousands rows -- sometimes less, occasionally more.

What is that status that we need? There are two relevant parameters per row: 1) the most recent month having had a date highlighted; 2) whether we are in a new month.

Indeed there is a built-in function in Google Sheet, `scan`, that performs exactly the above. To use it efficiently, we need a helper column.

For example, if in `D1` of the above example, we put in

```js
=let(dateRange,A1:A,
     numOfRow,rows(filter(dateRange,dateRange<>"")),
     choosecols(scan({0,0},array_constrain(dateRange,numOfRow,1),
                      lambda(a,c,if(month(c)>a,hstack(month(c),true)
                                              ,hstack(index(a,1,1),false))))
                ,2))
```

We can obtain a column of `TRUE`/`FALSE` which indicates whether a given row should be highlighted and you can use custom formula `=D1` for conditional formatting, as shown in the second image below.

Pay attention to the logic in `if` in the whole formula. First of all, `month(c)>a` is a shorthand for `month(c)>index(a,1,1)` in this case. The latter is better (clearer, more robust vs future updates). I only omitted it in the above formula for formatting (on StackOverflow) reasons.

The `index(a,1,1)` holds the previous month having had a highlighted date.

> The syntax itself stands for 1st cell of the accumulator and we use the 1st cell of the accumulator to hold the month number. We use the 2nd cell to store `TRUE`/`FALSE`, the flag for highlighting.

`c` is the (single) current cell that we are looking at, which contains the date we are to judge whether to highlight. If we require to only ever highlight dates from future months, we use `month(c)>...`. Had we wanted to allow for a date with an earlier month but merely different, we could use `month(c)<>...`.

Since we require that this date only be highlighted if it is of a different month (whether strictly later month, or just different) from the previously highlighted date (stored in `index(a,1,1)`), this solution allows for repeated dates.

This solution also allows for unsorted dates for the same reason.

We do end up with a helper column though. For personal use, I recommend keeping the helper column right next to your date column and hide it. If you want greater isolation between implementation and the sheet's frontend, you can move the helper column to a separate tab. Or you can create a *named variable* with a third-party tool (example: [dokin](https://www.dokin.co/dokin-tutorials/create-variables-in-google-sheets)).

> Hopefully in the future *named variable* will be a built-in feature

As well, in order to coerce `scan` to work with an infinite range, we had to use `array_constrain` to truncate the infinite range. That did require a first pass of check blank with `filter`. So we needed 2 passes. Still O(n). (Earlier solutions are at least O(n^2).)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That definitely returns the first instance of a date by month but wondering if there's a way to omit repeat dates? (e.g. if Jan 1 is repeated twice, to have only the first occurence highlighted).

Comment: @al-li: Yes. Separately, I was thinking about your problem and realized that it is probably best at least one of the solutions in all the answers is designed for a (very) large sheet. So I am going to edit my answer with such a solution and will build in a way to omit repeats. Hold on

Answer (score 2):

*You may try:*

```js
=xmatch(A1,sortn(A:A,9^9,2,eomonth(A:A,),))
```

[image]

---

***UPDATED FORMULA***

*pick **only** the first-occurrence of date & **skip** the concurrent duplicate(s) + other dates of **same month+year***

```js
=arrayformula(countif(eomonth(A$1:A1,),eomonth(A1,))=1)*(xmatch(A1,sortn(A:A,9^9,2,eomonth(A:A,),)))
```

[image]

Comment: **Updated** the formula to skip *duplicates* of first-matches

Comment: thank you, this seems to be working! If I wanted the whole row (e.g. A1:D1, A4:D4, etc.) to be highlighted as well, how would the formula need to be updated?

Comment: **Apply to range**: A:D **Custom formula**: `=arrayformula(countif(eomonth($A$1:$A1,),eomonth($A1,))=1)*(xmatch($A1,sortn($A:$A,9^9,2,eomonth($A:$A,),)))`

Comment: Ah ok thank you!! And laaaast question — if I wanted to apply the same logic but to the first occurence of the year instead of the month?

Comment: `=arrayformula(countif(year($A$1:$A1),year($A1))=1)*(xmatch($A1,sortn($A:$A,9^9,2,year($A:$A),)))`