# How to use infinite ranges in aggregating array functions such as `reduce` and `scan` along with `offset`?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What are the ways to use infinite ranges in aggregating array functions such as `reduce` and `scan` along with `offset`? Which is the more efficient way?

The motivation to use infinite ranges is of course to have the most flexible sheet possible with centralized formulas.

However, it is awkward to filter trailing blank cells in aggregating array functions. For example, consider this simple series of [running counts](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_uXpCCZCH2RRgb8tgc5wui4ssOmbyWr76nAwf8dCGg/edit#gid=139925362). If an infinite range such as `B2:B` was directly passed into `scan`, then `offset` could be conveniently used to access another column `A2:A`. However, checking blank within `lambda` wouldn't work to stop the scan at the last row cell with content, because *if blank, then doing nothing* in `scan` means passing the previous accumulator to next and thus the output will persist until Google Sheet cuts it off (every 1000 rows).

If we use `filter` to check blank, and thus obtain the number of non-blank rows. In-between blank cells not withstanding, we can then use `array_constrain` to limit the range in `reduce`/`scan` to a finite one. The good thing here is that `array_constrain` is likely a view (of references, the pointing kind) on the input and thus likely fast. Using `filter` to rid off trailing blank cells is so common that there is a chance that Google Sheet short-circuits the filter with [`.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow). In both cases, if not today, maybe in the future. *However*, the output of `array_constrain` is not an explicit range reference but is an inline array. Same with `chooserows(...,sequence(...),1)`. (But the latter, being potentially not contiguous, has the potential of being slow.) That means `offset` cannot be used to access other columns/rows, which would severely limit `reduce` and `scan` which only traverse arrays as if they were 1D. In the previous [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_uXpCCZCH2RRgb8tgc5wui4ssOmbyWr76nAwf8dCGg/edit#gid=139925362), we would have to array-concatenate and `flatten` column A and B and rely on the fact that the columns are distinct in data type: text vs number. Due to Google Sheet lacking access function for inline arrays, that will produce verbose code that is difficult to parse and the solution is still limiting.

And then there is performance concerns. In the past, `indirect` was described as a volatile function and having the potential of causing performance issues. `indirect` in conjunction with calculated max number of rows, of course, is another possibility as input into `reduce` and `scan` and would be compatible with `offset`. But what about performance? Will it be too slow with merely a few thousand rows and O(n^2) formulas? Compounding the issue is that it is cleaner and more readable to use built-in functions as much as possible. However, they tend to add unnecessary array traversals -- stepping O(n) problems up to O(n^2) solutions, for example. It would still be preferred to package solutions using built-in formulas. Think of using `filter`, `sumproduct`, `sumif` etc inside `scan` as opposed to using complex accumulators which Google Sheet in turn makes difficult to access and modify. (See [one of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049966/how-to-highlight-the-first-occurence-of-a-month-in-a-google-sheet/78050022#78050022) my [recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78071257/combine-duplicate-items-and-sum-up-values-within-a-single-string-cell/78072149#78072149) for examples of how verbose complex accumulators tend to get.) So, given a need to accommodate less performant algorithms, is `indirect` even worthwhile?

What about `offset`? If `indirect` was taboo, would `offset` be also off-limit? `offset` being the only(?) other function that outputs explicit range reference suitable for `offset` consumption.

Below is an example formula for the [earlier example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b_uXpCCZCH2RRgb8tgc5wui4ssOmbyWr76nAwf8dCGg/edit#gid=139925362) running counts using `offset` as input -- to make the preceding descriptions of formulas a bit more concrete. But it is incorrect unless the input data had been pre-prepossessed to rid of in-between blank rows. (Blank cell on the number can be a valid data entry -- even if blank cell on label is not.) I am going to leave the example formula incomplete as is though. Answers are where correct solutions are found.

```js
=let(input,B2:B
    ,numRow,rows(filter(input,input<>""))
    ,scan(0,offset(input,0,0,numRow,1)
         ,lambda(a,c
                ,if(offset(c,0,-1)=offset(c,-1,-1),a+c,c))))
```

Back to the initial question, hopefully I have motivated it sufficiently. What are the performant ways to use infinite ranges in aggregating array functions such as `reduce` and `scan` along with `offset`?

Perhaps if there is a list of options, one can then compare their relative performances and ease-of-use, or lack of.

In any case, any insights on performance would be helpful.

Comment: about `INDIRECT` (or `OFFSET`) being volatile in Google Sheets, we don't have concrete evidence to support this claim, in fact, I would say that the evidence we have points to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: @z..: Adding to that, although I could be wrong, I think the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/12189165?hl=en&ref_topic=9054603&sjid=15925701691622538380-NC) recently removed recommendation against `indirect`. (Somehow I think I saw it as recent as last month.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46883862/